# Plotting each loss in mask RCNN using Tensorboard

Tags: python, image-segmentation, tensorboard, loss, faster-rcnn

Have one doubt. I am also using mask rcnn but tensorflow is 2.0. I am trying to run the tensorboard but I am only getting one loss([plotting graph using tensorboard-only one loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXSa9.png)) instead of each loss graph. I am not sure how to retrieve each loss.
This is my code def compile section of model.py

```
    def compile(self, learning_rate, momentum):
    """Gets the model ready for training. Adds losses, regularization, and
    metrics. Then calls the Keras compile() function.
    """
    # Optimizer object
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(
        lr=learning_rate, momentum=momentum,
        clipnorm=self.config.GRADIENT_CLIP_NORM)
    loss_names = [
        "rpn_class_loss",  "rpn_bbox_loss",
        "mrcnn_class_loss", "mrcnn_bbox_loss", "mrcnn_mask_loss"]
    added_loss_name = []
    for name in loss_names:
        layer = self.keras_model.get_layer(name)
        if layer.output.name in added_loss_name:
        #if layer.output in self.keras_model.losses:
            continue
        loss = (
            tf.math.reduce_mean(layer.output, keepdims=True)
            * self.config.LOSS_WEIGHTS.get(name, 1.))
        self.keras_model.add_loss(loss)
        added_loss_name.append(layer.output.name)

    # Add L2 Regularization
    # Skip gamma and beta weights of batch normalization layers.
    reg_losses = [
        keras.regularizers.l2(self.config.WEIGHT_DECAY)(w) / tf.cast(tf.size(w), tf.float32)
        for w in self.keras_model.trainable_weights
        if 'gamma' not in w.name and 'beta' not in w.name]
    self.keras_model.add_loss(tf.add_n(reg_losses))

    # Compile
    self.keras_model.compile(
        optimizer=optimizer,
        loss=[None] * len(self.keras_model.outputs))

    # Add metrics for losses
    for name in loss_names:
        if name in self.keras_model.metrics_names:
            continue
        layer = self.keras_model.get_layer(name)
        self.keras_model.metrics_names.append(name)
        loss = (
            tf.reduce_mean(layer.output, keepdims=True)
            * self.config.LOSS_WEIGHTS.get(name, 1.))
        self.keras_model.metrics.append(loss)
```

**I want to see each loss seperately instead of one single loss like the image given below( matterport /Mask_RCNN ).**
[separate losses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RSLv.png)

Comment: I'm having some difficulty understanding what exactly you want. Can you elaborate a little more? Do you what to visualize the training loss and the validation loss in two separate plots?

Comment: not exactly. I can ellborate more clearly.

Comment: I am getting an error like     "OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function." This is error is for tensorflow 1.12 version of  matterport /Mask_RCNN . But the code I provided  above is for tf2.0, but in this all the losses got appended.